# How do I get a Faye client given a client ID?

Tags: ruby, faye

Faye allows you to monitor various events, such as `handshake` or `subscribe`.  These callback blocks are only supplied the `client_id` value rather than the client itself.  For example:

```
server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(mount: '/faye', timeout: 45)

server.bind(:handshake) do |client_id|
  puts "Received handshake from #{client_id}"
end
```

How can I access the client given the `client_id`?  Or how can I access more information in the handshake, such as cookies provided in the request header (if that info is even available)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think my original question is based upon a lack of understanding on how Faye works in two regards.  Instead of deleting my question, I'm going to answer it for anyone else who comes across this with a similar question.  (If my answer is wrong in any way, please comment or edit!)

First, at no point is access to the connected client available due to the way Faye is implemented with regards to the Bayeux protocol.  All communications are carried out via channel broadcasting, meaning all connections listening to a channel will receive the message being sent.

Second, the code I pasted in the question deals with [monitoring](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/monitoring.html).  What I'm really looking for is an [extension](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/extensions.html).

In order to achieve authentication given my original question, I need to pass whatever authentication value is needed (whether it's a cookie value, auth token, etc.) as part of the `message['ext']` value (per the example on the extensions page).  Then, on the server side, I need to listen for messages on the `/meta/handshake` channel, setting `message['error']` to some value in the case of value.