# How do I get clientId who published the message using faye

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sockets, thin, faye

I have implemented `faye` for chatting services. But I want to know how can I find the clientId of that person who published the msg. I tried this:

```
faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45)
faye_server.bind(:publish) do |clientId, channel, data|
   puts "client_id is #{clientId}"
end
```

But it gives me a blank ID. How can I fetch the clientID?

Comment: I have the same problem with the Node version - the clientId I get through the `bayeux.on('publish'...` monitoring function is coming through as undefined...

Comment: Not sure if this is any help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12519602/1772200